# Regular Expression QT

Tags: regex, qt

I want to allow only the characters `%`, `S`, `C`, `D`, `-` in my string with
starting with `%` and not allow to have doubles `%%` or `CC`.

I tried `^%[%DSC-]{1,1}+$` but it do not work. If I use `^%[%DSC-]+$` I can write `%%` as sample.

Any Idea how I can limit this? I use the `QRegEx` in Qt.

Comment: please check my answer, I think it should help.

Comment: Question is not well defined. Give couple positive an negative examples.

Comment: And what is `not allow to have doubles %% or CC`? Only at the start of the string or the whole string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?!.*(.)\\1)%[%SCD-]*$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vM1tO8/1)

With `(?!.*(.)\\1)` lookahead, it disallows any consecutively repeating symbol anywhere in the input string. (Note that in Qt, the backslash in a regex pattern must be doubled).

The first `%` makes it compulsory as the first character in the string.

The `[%SCD-]*` character class allows the string to only contain 0 or more `%`, `S`, `C`, `D`, or `-` symbols.

`^` anchors the match at the beginning of the string, and `$` anchor it at its end.

Note: If you want make the regex case-insensitive, use `regex.setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive)`.

**UPDATE**:

Since the question is not 100% clear, I should note that in case you want to only disallow `CC` or `%%`, use

```
^(?!.*([C%])\\1)%[%SCD-]*$
```

Comment: Looking at @pixbye requests I do think this is a solution because you won't accept %SS (for example) while I think it should be acceptable (only repeated `C` seems to be not acceptable)

Comment: @MorixDev: You have a point. I have been working with people from all over the world, and am so accustomed to typos, poor English, understatements, that I automatically assumed `%%` or `CC` are just examples describing a general pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be enough:

```
^%(%|)([DSC-]{1,2})+
```

Comment: I don't think so: for example the string `%CC` is matched by your regex but it is not acceptable (if I understood @pixbye requirements)

Comment: Then clarify your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a solution:

`^((?<!%)%(?!%)(D|S|-|(C(?!C))|(%(?!%)))*)$`

you can try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/nW5nK2/2).

Comment: Sorry, but your requirements are not clear... your string must always start with `%` and be followed by at least one char? Furthermore: why `%D` should not be allowed? which part of your requirements says that?

Comment: Sorry for messing around with your answer. I restored your last version.

Comment: @pixbye: for dealing with single `%` being allowed, you can simply replace `*` with `+` in my answer and that is fixed; regarding `%D` that should not be allowed then I think you have to provide further details about what you want to do... in your description nothing lead me thinking that `%D` should not be allowed

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
^(?!%%)%(?:(?!%{2}|c{2})[%DCS-])+$
```

**Explanation**

`(?!%%)` prevent for `%%` at starting of the string by using negative look ahead,

`(?:(?!%{2}|C{2})[%DCS-])+` is expanded to `(#)[%DCS-](#)[%DCS-](#)[%DCS-](#)[%DCS-]...` where `(#)` is `(?![%C]{2})` for making sure that there is no `%%` and `CC` in the rest of your string.

The last one is quite tricky where you can spawn a negative look head to in front of every characters (`[%DCS-]`).

Note that regex above is standard from (`perl`) please improve it according to your using language.

DEMO:
https://regex101.com/r/oO8jR3/3

Answer (score 0):

Question doesn't give good description what you want to capture by regular expression so I'm guessing that this is what you need:

`^(%[SCD-])+$`

This will match:

- `%D%-`
- `%S%C%S`

But will not match:

- `%%D%C`
- `%D%%C`
- `%DD%C`
- `%DC%C`

you can try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/vD5bL6/1) (and click unit test tool).