# QT Regular Expression

Tags: regex, qt

Yesterday I asked about a expression on how to limit the possibilities:

> Add only %D , %C ,%S and the char -

Everything only one time and so it is not allowed to make %% or %DD or -- and similar.

The answer I got was:

```
^(?!.*(.)\\1)%[%SCD-]*$
```

This is the answer to my question but I also need to limit %D, %S and %C one time in the string.

Any Idea how to limit this to only one time?

```
One time: %D-%D .... <- Not
```

Comment: So, what are valid and invalid? Can you provide that please?

Comment: valid is %S-%D-%C
not valid:
What is not %S %D %C 
the three % values are placeholder for a string pattern
%S is for String
%D is for Date
%C is for Counter
It is only allowed to have each pattern 1 time.But it is also allowed to use not a pattern. So if the user wants, the final string can be %S but not %S %S

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of to do what you are asking with a regular expression is to use permutations of all the possible inputs and make a big or'ed statement with many regular expressions.  With four possible inputs only appearing once, you are left with 16 possible permutations.

Example:

```
(ABC)|(ACB)|(CBA)|(CAB)|(BAC)|(BCA)
```

The more generic/practical way to handle this is to leverage the `QValidator` class.

I would subclass `QValidator` and make it your own.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvalidator.html#details

When the input is invalid or not working, I would have another nearby label updating in real time removing excess input so it shows what is allowed from what they have entered.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I use the RedEx for my own Validator.

mDiskCustomPattern = new QLineEdit(ConfigurationPage::mSettings.value("CustomDiskNamePattern", tr("%S-%D-%C")).toString(), this);

QRegExp regx("^(?!.*(.)\\1)%[%SCD-]*$");

QValidator *validator = new QRegExpValidator(regx, mDiskCustomPattern);

mDiskCustomPattern->setValidator( validator );

Comment: In all, if Iam allowed to limit the chars to [%SCD-] it must be possible to limit SCD to one time usage.

Answer (score 0):

[Yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32261368/regular-expression-qt/32264888#32264888), I give you this regex with a [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oO8jR3/3)

```
^(?!%%)%(?:(?!%{2}|c{2})[%DCS-])+$
```

You told that want your string start with `%[DCS-]` (but not `^%%` ) and the following string should not have a double `%` or `c`.

The regex that you've shown above it's totally not full filled your requirement, I don't know why you give that answer correct.

Anyway, according to your problem, this should work

```
^(?!%%|%D.*?%D|%C.*?%C|%S.*?%S)%(?:(?!%D.*?%D|%C.*?%C|%S.*?%S)[%DCS-])+$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sS2lM4/1)

Comment: Exact at the time I entered %D it is true that I cannot enter %D not anymore, but also with your solution I cannot add %S or %C after added %D. The answer I accepted did exact what I wanted. And now I want to limit it to %D, %C and %S to one time.

Comment: @pixbye How about my second regex, that ans your question?

Comment: Sorry, no. After added %S-% Iam not allowed to enter D or C, so your demo shows %S-%D not match.

Comment: Your requirement is totally unclear, don't let other people guess because you will very slow approach to the correct answer. Please, provide your infomation strictly and nicely.

Comment: Please check a correctness of my answer first then I will add more explanation for you later.

Comment: definitly wrong. Look, %D-%%-DD is allowed with your idea. Sorry, but I think my needs are no clue or magic issue. I just want to make sure that the patterns are added correctly. I have only three patterns: %D, %S, %C this is are the maximal patterns. User can add 1 or two or three but always just one of each.  %D-%D is wrong, %%D is wrong, %D-%% is wrong. Each pattern max. one time. Connected with a "-"

Comment: Iam also confused about the regex101.com, it seems this tool has bugs. In QT it is not allowed with the regex: ^(?!.*(.)\\1)%[%-DSC]*$ to add %D-%%, on regex101.com it is allowed with the same regex.